# angular2 - the pipe could not be found when grouping records

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I fetch data from an API and returns it into view which works properly. But i'm finding it hard to group the data by date. 
When i try i get this error: `The pipe 'groupBy' could not be found`

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform{
  transform(value: Array<any>, field:string): Array<any> {
    if (value) {
      const groupedObj = value.reduce((prev, cur) =>{
        if(!prev[cur[field]]) {
          prev[cur[field]] = [cur]
        } else{
          prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
        }

        return prev;
      }, {});

      return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedObj[key] }));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

view.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of list | groupBy:'date_ph'" no-lines >
<ion-item>
<ion-icon name="calendar" item-start color="light"></ion-icon>
   <h2>Date</h2>
<ion-note color="dark" item-end>{{item.date_ph}} </ion-note>
</ion-item>
    </ion-item>
```

view.ts

```
import { GroupByPipe } from '../../pipes/groupby/groupby';
import {Component, Pipe} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-view',
  templateUrl: 'view.html'

})
```

Comment: Put pipe in a module's declaration list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `view.ts` file you imported `GroupByPipe`

```
import { GroupByPipe } from '../../pipes/groupby/groupby';
```

It would not work for your `view.html` file

you have to declare it in your `app.module.ts` file:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GroupByPipe
  ],
})
```

Alternatively, you can import GroupByPipe into your component as [Swanand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6620976/swanand)
suggested:

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'page-view', 
  templateUrl: 'view.html'
  providers : [GroupByPipe]
 }) export class NameComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private groupByPipe: GroupByPipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // invoke groupByPipe here based on your logic
  }

}
```

Comment: followed your answer and i'm not getting the error again but the data is in the is not showing up

Comment: @user6579134 now your custom pipe has been imported properly, your custom pipe probably not work as you expected. add some debug lines see what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your service in your component.

```
import { GroupByPipe } from '../../pipes/groupby/groupby';
import {Component, Pipe} from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({ 
selector: 'page-view', 
templateUrl: 'view.html'
providers : [GroupByPipe]
 })
```

If it is not working then try to add it in module.ts file.